# Pushing content page from background thread freezes app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms for iOS, I have a custom renderer for a ContentPage that displays a video control. In my Xamarin Forms app, this custom ContentPage is displayed inside a NavigationPage.
I would like to have the video screen open when a specific message comes in via MQTT.

When I open the video page by clicking a link on the main screen, it opens as expected. I know I am receiving the message via MQTT and calling `Navigation.PushModalAsync()` because of console statements and breakpoints. However, the custom rendered page is not displayed and the UI of my app freezes each time after calling `PushModalAsync`.

Is there something else I need to do to trigger `Navigation.PushModalAsync()` based on receiving an MQTT notification in the background of my app?

ViewRoomsPage.axml.cs:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ViewRoomsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ViewRoomsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string StreamUri { get; set; }
}
```

ViewRoomsPage.axml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyForms.Pages.ViewRoomsPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

VideoViewerRenderer.cs (video code removed; this should display a blank red screen. It also works when launched from a button on the main screen)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewRoomsPage), typeof(ViewRoomsRenderer))]
namespace MyForms.IOS.NativeImplementations
{
    public class ViewRoomsRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private IJKFFMoviePlayerController _playerController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            e.NewElement.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Method triggered from receiving an MQTT message

```
    public void PushViewRooms()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ViewRoomsPage());
        });
    }
```

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        SetupDependencies(); // using StructureMap
        Manager = DependencyContainer.Resolve<IMqttManager>();
        Manager.Connect();            

        InitializeComponent();

        var mainPage = new MainPage();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigation needs to happen on main thread.

Comment: Right, hence wrapping the Navigation.Push call in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`

Comment: where is `PushViewRooms()` invoked from?

Comment: An MQTT receiver that runs in the background while my app is running. 
Does Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread not move operations to the main thread?

Comment: You sure the triggered method is actually being called?

Comment: Yes, a breakpoint set in that method gets hit when it's called.

Comment: It appears that the code inside BeginInvokeOnMainThread isn't called at all. PushAsync gets called if I take out the BeginInvokeOnMainThread, but the freezing behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a deadlock caused by a `Task.WaitAll()` being triggered in another section of code running in the background.

Thanks all who helped sanity check that it wasn't something in the way the renderer was set up.